# Reference request for embedding of a tensor product $C^*$-algebra

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, tensor-products, crossed-products

I am studying Ruy Exel's paper "A new look at the crossed product of a $C^*$-algebra by a semigroup of endomorphisms." In the proof of Theorem 11.7 he writes:

Let $G$ be ameanable, thus $C^*(G)$ is nuclear. As a consequence, $B(H) \otimes C^*(G)$ embeds faithfully in $B(H \otimes \ell^2(G))$ in such a way that for all $T \in B(H), g \in G$, $T \otimes u_g$ is mapped to $T \otimes \lambda_g$, where $\lambda_g$ is the left regular representation as usual.

My question is what does he mean by "embeds faithfully", more concretely, the "faithfully" part.

Moreover, a reference to this result is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Faithful here means injective. "Embeds faithfully" just means that there is a canonical injective $^*$-homomorphism with the given description (which follows since the canonical map $C^*(G) \to C^*_r(G)$ is an isomorphism by amenability and by definition of the spatial(=minimal) $C^*$-tensor product). I would suggest that future questions along this line are posted in Math Stack Exchange instead of here.

Comment: @JamieGabe Thank you! I posted the question here due to the reference part, by any chance, do you know one?

Comment: Theorem 2.6.8 in Brown's and Ozawa's book contains the relevant results for amenable groups. Combined with the definition of the minimal tensor product, this gives your result.